# Prevent ImageView drawing outside the bounds of parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an Image view with a zooming capability

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/helfie_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="center" />
```

it is in a parent with a drawable with top corner radius:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:outlineProvider="background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/sheet_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- including the photoview -->
            <include

                android:id="@+id/preview_layout_frame"
                layout="@layout/preview_snaped_helfie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/helfie_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="20dp" />


        </LinearLayout>
```

and here's  the `sheet_bg`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/dark" />
    <!--<stroke-->
        <!--android:width="5dp"-->
        <!--android:color="@color/white" />-->
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="35dp"
        android:topRightRadius="35dp"

        />
</shape>
```

I have trying everything from `clipChildren` to `clipPadding` to make sure the ImageView does not draw outside the bounds of the linear layout, none has worked so far. Using a cardview does the fix (but this fails on some devices and I only need the top corner radius).

How the layout background looks like

[image: How the layout background looks like]

How the PhotoView looks like with an image.
[image: How the PhotoView looks like with an image.]

As you can see, it spans out of the curve bounds of the parent.

Comment: I have used `clipchildren = false` . Didn't work still

Comment: @pskink no, any info on how I can achieve what I have in mind ?

Comment: did you find any solution

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? This is still an issue =(

Answer (score 0):

Its probaby too late for you but someone may still need this solution :)

I've created a CustomConstraintLayout to prevent its children pushing outside of parent's bounds.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


/**
 * Created by Payam Monsef
 * At: 2022/Jun/27
 */
class CustomConstraintLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    private var topRadius = 64F

    private var mPath: Path? = null
    private var mPaint: Paint? = null

    init {
        mPath = Path()
        mPaint = Paint()
        mPaint?.style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
        mPaint?.color = Color.GRAY
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        mPath?.apply {
            reset()
            val radiusArr = floatArrayOf(
                topRadius, topRadius,
                topRadius, topRadius,
                0f, 0f,
                0f, 0f
            )

           addRoundRect(
                RectF(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat()),
                radiusArr,
                Path.Direction.CW
           )
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        mPath?.let {
            mPaint?.let { paint ->
                canvas.drawPath(it, paint)
            }
            canvas.clipPath(it)
        }
    }
}
```